# jsplumb - Endpoints linger after duplicate connection deleted

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jsplumb

I'm using `jsPlumb` to create/delete connections between different `div` boxes. I found the following function to delete any duplicate connections.

```
jsPlumb.bind('connection', function(info) {
    var con = info.connection;
    var arr = jsPlumb.select({source:con.sourceId, target:con.targetId});
    if ( arr.length>1 ) {
        jsPlumb.detach(con);
    }
});
```

When this executes, it leaves the endpoint floating in the middle of the page. And it is no longer attached to the `div`.

I've also tried deleting all endpoints for when a duplicate is found, but that dot still just lingers.

[Endpoint Just Lingering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SI4d.png)

How do I get rid of that dot when duplicates are removed? Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks!